# Reporting Status for conditional jobs with Github Actions

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to have conditional checks, based on paths on various files/folders so that if certain files are not changed, do not run the validation on them. E.g., run terraform validation if and only if `*.tf` were changed. Similarly, run JS linting/formatting only if `*.js` files were touched.

Additionally, these checks are *required*.

Github Actions code

```
name: Validate Terraform Files


on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'terraform/**'
```

```
name: Validate JS Files


on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'src/**/*.js'
```

On Github's side, `Validate Terraform Files` & `Validate JS Files` are Required status checks.

However, with this setup, if there are no changes on `'terraform/**'`, then that status check never runs and doesn't report anything back.

[image]

And same thing happens with `Validate JS Files` checks when the changeset has no JS files.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to make them report a status back even if they are not run or skipped. Is there a way to make this work? Have conditionally run status checks report back?

Comment: Maybe you could use the `always()` function in an `if` block such that the step at the `if` block will always run: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#always

Comment: It won't get to the `if` part if the path doesn't match. I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve this by using two chained tasks. Unfortunately it requires adding `if`s to every step and won't skip powering-up job `services`. I think it's still worth it though.

```
name: Validate JS Files

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 1
    outputs:
      js_changed: ${{ steps.js_changed.outputs.changed }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - run: git fetch origin main

      - id: js_changed
        name: Check if dorm-fe has been changed
        run: >
          if grep -q "src/.*/.*\.js" <<< $(git diff --name-only origin/main --);
          then echo "changed=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
          else echo "changed=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
          fi

  verify-js:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    needs: check

    steps:
      - name: No changes detected
        if: ${{ needs.check.outputs.js_changed == 'false' }}
        run: echo "No changes, nothing to do ¯\_(ツ)_/¯"

      - name: Checkout branch
        if: ${{ needs.check.outputs.js_changed == 'true' }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        if: ${{ needs.check.outputs.js_changed == 'true' }}
        run: npm install

      - name: Run verify
        if: ${{ needs.check.outputs.js_changed == 'true' }}
        run: npm verify
```